# Can you bounce App Pool from within w3wp.exe itself?

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-6

Easy as that. Any security considerations? IIS6, IIS7? Or just write something to the config from the same process to trigger the recycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of recycling the application pool without having to write to the config file would be:

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

[HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx)